# Issue in audio pubnub webrtc for android

Tags: android, webrtc, pubnub

Hey friends i am working on pubnub webrtc android tutorial.

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC).

I already changed the username and put my name in the [VideoChatActivity.java](https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/kevingleason/androidrtc/VideoChatActivity.java) class.

But my issue is when call to a connected, publisher hears the sound of subscriber but the subscriber does not hear the publisher's sound...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known issue. I believe it was recently fixed. There was a bug in the value of `OfferReceiveAudio` which prevented two way audio from being transmitted.

For now, you would have to clone the repository and add it to your project. I will rebuild the artifacts and host them to be accessible via gradle shortly.

For more information refer to the following pull request:

https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC/pull/14